# Cannot install Python Package with docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am running a Django project with docker. Now I want to install a Python package inside the Docker container and run the following command:

`docker-compose django run pip install django-extra-views`

Now when I do `docker-compose up`, I get an error `ImportError: No module named 'extra_views'`. `docker-compose django run pip freeze` doesn't show the above package either.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you ran the `pip install` in a one-off container. That means your package isn't going to be installed in subsequent containers created with `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose run`. You need to install your dependencies in the *image*, usually by adding the `pip install` command to your Dockerfile. That way, all containers created from that image will have the dependencies available.

Comment: Do I need to rebuild the container in order to install a new package?

Comment: You need to rebuild the *image*.